# HTML5: How to get currentTime and duration of Audio Tag in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I am using HTML5 audio tag for playing sound files in my template. For some purpose I need to track the currentTime and duration which shows upto milliseconds. Now I am able to get the values in seconds only. Is there any possible methods? Below is my code:

```
HTML
<audio controls id="track" src="<path-to-soundtrack>"
   ontimeupdate="TrackAudio(this)">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>


JAVASCRIPT
function TrackAudio(element){
var curTime = Math.floor(element.currentTime);
console.log(curTime)   //Value in seconds.
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `Math.floor` here. Without `Math.floor`, the value of `element.currentTime` _should_ contain as much precision as the browser can afford. Hence, `element.currentTime * 1000` should give you the current time in milliseconds. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @musically_ut: Yeah, that could be more helpful. Its possible to use the precision values for showing the time value upto milliseconds. Great Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
<audio id="track" controls>
  <source src="your.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="your.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var audio = document.getElementById('track');
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
    var currentTimeMs = audio.currentTime*1000;
    console.log(currentTimeMs);
},false);
</script>
```

You can read here for more information on the precision of the timeupdate [event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325787/setting-the-granularity-of-the-html5-audio-event-timeupdate). It is dependent on the browser implementation so keep in mind you will get different results from a browser/device to another.

You should use addEventListener method rather than the ontimeupdate property - it is more maintainable.

Also if you need browser coverage it is good to use both ogg and mp3 audio files as sources.

Comment: This answer does not explain how you get the total time of the file.