# Project: Tracking a bouncing ball across a music score

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio-player

May I ask for some assistance with this project? I have had some initial success getting a div containing a ball shape to scroll across the top of a music score in time with the audio. I've only got as far as the top line of music but have deliberately chosen this stage to ask for advice. The url for work in progress is http://test.101drums.com/index.html and click on the lesson "Tea Time" and play the track. Apologies for not completing the styling for the index page! I have also set up a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/tciprop/0quwsxd2/ but this is for some reason not working.
You will see I am using the "ontimeupdate" event to move the ball and the ratio of "currentTime/duration" with some maths to allow for various factors, such as start position, a 2 bar introduction in the audio, and the dimensions of the music score image.
I have a very jerky ball! I will have to develop this for different music score layouts but have chosen the commonest format in the range of lessons to start.
I could probably tidy the maths up as well. All advice will be gratefully received, perhaps starting with getting the fiddle to work. It seems to work when you run the code snippet.
The fiddle code is:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("lessonTrack");
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
var lessonScore = document.getElementById("lessonScore");
ball.style.left = (0.071 * lessonScore.offsetWidth) + "px";
audio.load();
function updateProgress() {
  var ballarea = lessonScore.offsetWidth;
  if (audio.currentTime > (2 / 19 * audio.duration)) {
    ball.style.left = (0.071 * ballarea) + ((19 / 4 * (0.885 * ballarea)) * (audio.currentTime/audio.duration)) - (2 / 4 * (0.885 * ballarea)) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#lessonScore
{
  width: 100%;
}
#ballarea
{
    position: relative;
}

#ball
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 2vw;
    height: 2vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1vh;
    left: 1vw;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="ballarea">
    <img id="lessonScore" src="http://test.101drums.com/scores/02_teatime.jpg" alt="Score">
    <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
<audio id="lessonTrack" controls ontimeupdate="updateProgress()">
                <source id="mp3" src="http://test.101drums.com/tracks/mp3/02_teatime.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                <source id="ogg" src="" type="audio/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the audio player.
</audio>
```

Comment: Here's my progress so far: https://jsfiddle.net/tciprop/0quwsxd2/38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this StackOverflow post [Setting the granularity of the HTML5 audio event 'timeupdate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325787/setting-the-granularity-of-the-html5-audio-event-timeupdate), it seems that you can't control when the `ontimeupdate` event will fire.

What you can do however, is manually control when `updateProgress` gets called by using `setInterval`:

```
// Update progress every 100ms
setInterval(updateProgress, 100);
```

Update your markup to remove the ontimeupdate attribute:

```
<audio id="lessonTrack" controls>
                <source id="mp3" src="http://test.101drums.com/tracks/mp3/02_teatime.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                <source id="ogg" src="" type="audio/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the audio player.
</audio>
```

**NOTE**: You'll have better performance using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`. To do so, instead of calling `setInterval` you would:

```
requestAnimationFrame(updateProgress);
```

And you would modify `updateProgress` to queue another update by calling `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
function updateProgress() {
  var ballarea = lessonScore.offsetWidth;
  if (audio.currentTime > (2 / 19 * audio.duration)) {
    ball.style.left = (0.071 * ballarea) + ((19 / 4 * (0.885 * ballarea)) * (audio.currentTime/audio.duration)) - (2 / 4 * (0.885 * ballarea)) + "px";
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(updateProgress);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out.